# FLTK Wait for event to close window

Tags: c++, user-interface, fltk

I basically have a window with an in_box and an enter button. How can I make it so that the window stays open and drawn until the user types into the in_box and hits the enter button.

```
Window w(Point(100,100),200,200, "Category Sales");
Button enter(Point(25,25),110,25,"Enter",enter);
In_box cat_in(Point(75,75),100,20,"Category:");
w.attach(cat_in);
w.attach(enter);
Fl::wait();
if(ent==true)
{
category = cat_in.get_string();
reference_to<My_button>(addr).receiver->do_categories();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this rather than have an enter button?

Answer (score 1):

Fl::wait() is the wrong function for this. (Read the documentation for more details what that function is all about)

What you really need is to call Fl::run() at the end of that function. (I assume that is inside the main() function). I strongly suggest you read the (pretty good) FLTK 1 documentation, and get familiar with the toolkit. A good source of information are the examples inside the source tree.